# Updating other table column after insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have these two  table called  "cases" and attendance respectively which has four columns:

```
cases-
 id  empid     reaction    date_t
 1   EMP12654 interested   2017-09-22

 attendance-

id empid    logintime logouttime   date_t      flag  workinghours call_att
1  EMP12654 00:14:49   05:14:49    2017-09-18  set      6          1
```

What I want to do is create a trigger on cases table that updates call_att column of attendance table with number of entries in reaction column of cases table, this is what I have tried so far

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `number_call` 
AFTER INSERT ON `cases` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN UPDATE attendance set call_att=call_att +1 
WHERE empid=new.empid AND date_t=new.date_t; END
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I am quite new to triggers.

Comment: Please share the table cases and attendance as text data tables with example data.

Comment: if possible also add the error message in question , so it is easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
CREATE TRIGGER number_call 
    AFTER INSERT ON cases
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE attendance set call_att=(select count(*) from cases where empid=NEW.empid )
date_t=NEW.date_t;
END
```

Comment: Its not giving me an error but also not updating the call_att column!!